# Using singularity analysis to find the main asymptotic term of the Catalan Numbers

Tags: asymptotics, catalan-numbers

Using singularity analysis to find the main asymptotic term of the Catalan Numbers

\begin{align}
C_n = [z^n]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}
\end{align}

*Can someone please explain to me the general concept of singularity analysis?* I understand that you are supposed to find the main singularity (in this case it is when z = 1/4). And then you create a power series expanded about this singularity but I don't know how to do that. Any hints and tips are appreciated.